# Hibernate @OneToMany Set lose his order when received in API endpoint

Tags: java, json, hibernate, api, one-to-many

I'm having trouble receiving ordered data in a java API endpoint from react front-end.

In particular it is a JSON array which contains inside recursively objects and arrays in a tree-structure like in the sample written below

Question: how can I receive my subChildren array that is mapped by Hibernate inside Set subChildren, in the correct order? I'm probably missing some hibernate annotation or something else

If I go in debug mode I found out that just after entering in the first code line of method savePeopleByDynastyId() the Set subChildren inside of peopleList has lost is order.

(correct order I want to achieve for Person objects: child1,child2,child3)

Is it the only way to send them with and Id already(I would prefer to avoid it)? If yes, what annotation should I add to the `@OneToMany private Set<Person> subChildren` to achieve that? I've tried `@OrderBy(value = "id")` but it's not working

Any help is appreciated!

JSON data sent using Postman to simulate the POST request :
http://localhost:8080/api/dynasty/people

```
  [
     {
      name: father,
      age: 50,
      subChildren : [
        {
            name: child1,
            age: 30,
            subChildren : []
        },
        {
            name: child2,
            age: 28,
            subChildren : []
        },
        {
            name: child3,
            age: 26,
            subChildren : []
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Person.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;


    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_PARENT")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Person parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @OrderBy(value = "id")
    private Set<Person> subChildren  = new LinkedHashSet<Person>();
    
    public Person(){}

    //Getter and Setter
    
}
```

DynastyController.java:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/api/dynasty")
public class DynastyController {

    @PostMapping("/people")
    public ResponseEntity<?> savePeopleByDynastyId(@RequestBody Iterable<Person> peopleList, BindingResult result){
        
        Iterable<Person> newPeopleList = null;
        for (Person person : peopleList) {
            //intention : cycle through each person of subChildren array recursively and persist each of his person 
        }
        ResponseEntity<Iterable<Person>> responseEntity= new ResponseEntity<>(newPeopleList, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        return responseEntity;
    }
}
```

Comment: The orderby id is not working may be bcz you don't have id in response list. Try including id in response and check.

Comment: thank you for reply.  I've tried it with id in the response list but it wasn't working. I didn't put id in the question because I would like to find a solution without sending id from front-end because I believe they should be generated in the business layer when the object  get persisted in db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is in the deserialization done by Jackson. It replaces the collection with a plain `HashSet` instead of adding to the existing `LinkedHashSet`. Try using the `LinkedHashSet` type as declared type in the entity.

Comment: unfortunately I can't change the set in a linkedHashSet because it won't compile , Hibernate requires:
 'One To Many' attribute type should be [java.util.Collection, java.util.List, java.util.Set]

Comment: Did you check, is the type of the set still a linked hash set after deserialization?

Comment: By debugging into your controller method and checking the object type of the variable.

Comment: I confirm it is a HashSet, what can I do?

Comment: According to Hibernate documentation by adding @OrderBy annotation the Set should be converted to a LinkedHashSet  ordered by the value specified, so you are saying the problem is that before Hibernate acts, Jackson deserialize the JSON array into an HashSet

Comment: I'm saying that Jackson constructs this object this way, so Hibernate has no play in this. Just use `@JsonDeserialize(as=LinkedHashSet.class)` on the field.

Comment: Thank you so much Christian ! That annotation on the setter has solved the problem !